# Is Tails browser same as separate Tor bundle-browser?

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, tails

It seem to be somehow different, is it still FF-based? Or is there any possibility to use tails and then use Tor bundle same way as you use it in Windows?

And of course, is Tails's browser's security in same level as Tor Bundle?

Comment: Tails routes all of your traffic through Tor; there is no reason to open the TBB inside of Tails.

Answer (score 1):

No; it uses a modded version of Firefox, not straight TBB.
https://tails.boum.org/forum/Tor_Browser_Bundle/
https://tails.boum.org/doc/about/features/index.en.html

Answer (score 0):

Tails is based on Debian which uses Iceweasel which is just a rebrand of Firefox.

Source:
https://tails.boum.org/doc/anonymous_internet/Tor_Browser/index.en.html